# Complex filters in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I want to query my Django model with a filter like this:

```
(pseudo code)
field1values = ['val11','val12']
field2values = ['val21','val22']
result = (field1 == 'val11' | field1 == 'val12') & (field2 == 'val21' | field2 == 'val22')
```

If I had to query for only field1 here the code could look like this:

```
    clauses = []
    for item in field1values:
        clauses.append(MyModel.objects.filter(field1=item))
        result = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, clauses)
```

But I cannot figure out how to create the filters for the complex predicate that I want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Q objects.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
resultquery = (Q(field1='val11') | Q(field1='val12')) & ...
result = SomeModel.objects.filter(resultquery)
```

Also, [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can u rewrite this if the values are coming from a list. I do not know what the values in the list are so cannot hard code them

Comment: okay, the IN clause you have mentioned worked well for the lists. result = MyModel.objects.filter(filed1__in = field1values). And then result = result.filter(filed2__in = field2values). Thanks